# Image (Numbers/Letters) recognition

Tags: c++, image, opencv, screenshot

I'm learning C++ for half a year now (so programming in general) and this site always had the answers I was looking for. But now I came to the point where I need to ask as I couldn't find anything related to my question.

So I want to write a program that takes a screenshot of a particular area of the screen. This screenshot will ONLY contain playcards (so for example Hearth, Seven). What it should do now is return me which card it is, so the symbol and the number/letter.

I already made some researches and the most mentioned thing was the library "OpenCV".

So my question now: First is it even possible with my experience to write something like that?

If so, is this library the way to go? It seems really strong, maybe too strong for just the recognition of numbers/letters and four symbols? So could there be something easier?

And the last question, how could I get a screenshot  of a particular area of the screen and not the whole screen and save it somewhere?

I hope you guys have a clue what I really want to know and it was understandable.

Greetings

Comment: You may also want to try looking around on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: "just the recognition" is a "strong" task. you will find out soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely use OpenCV. It is not too hard to get into, and once you do you will find it does basically everything you'd want. It makes image processing relatively straightforward and it can solve your problem in a lot of ways.

[Here](http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/) is a good place to start.